# How to duplicate and rename all Jenkins jobs?

Tags: jenkins

I have a bunch of jobs triggered by commits on gitlab. The problem is, that the branch specifier in those jobs is `origin/${gitlabSourceBranch}`. Whenever I want to manually re-run the job I have to go inside job configuration, change it to `origin/master`, and than run. I want to avoid this situation and make a complete copy of all those jobs and put them into different tab, with `-manual` at their name's end.

My jobs look like this:

```
[Unit-test-tab]
ModuleName1-unit-test-python
ModuleName2-unit-test-python
ModuleName3-unit-test-java
etc...
```

I want to make a copy of all those jobs and put them in Jenkins under `[Unit-test-tab-manual]` with the same names with added `-manual-` at the end. So basically I want to make a tab looking like this:

```
[Unit-test-tab-manual]
ModuleName1-unit-test-python-manual
ModuleName2-unit-test-python-manual
ModuleName3-unit-test-java-manual
etc... (all with branch specifier changed to origin/master instead of origin/${gitlabSourceBranch)).
```

Is there any quick solution for this? I know I can do it manually but it is time consuming and I have a lot of those jobs. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI%20%22Jenkins%20CLI) to achieve what you want. It does provide a command to create jobs passing a config.xml as input.To change the branch, you can use a `sed` to change "origin/${gitlabSourceBranch}" to "origin/master".

You can do all this with a Jenkins Job that:

1. Takes the config.xml file of the job with the `get-job` CLI command: `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://jenkins.example.com get-job JOBNAME > config.xml`
2. Execute the sed on the config.xml of the job; the sed should be something like this: `sed -i 's/origin\/${gitlabSourceBranch}/origin\/master/g' config.xml`
3. Creates the new job with a different name using the create-job CLI command: `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://jenkins.example.com create-job JOBNAME-manual < config.xml`